# Javascript Sort Date and time from String

Tags: javascript

I have a list of objects named rides and I want to get the time and date fields and want to sort the data in **ascending order**

```
[
  {
    bookingID: "Booking ID# 34120",
    date: "Wed, 13 Jan",
    destinationAddress: "4, Port Louis, Maurice",
    numberOfPersons: "1",
    pickupAddress: "A 33, Goodlands, Maurice",
    requestMadeOn: "08:12:06 \nWed 13 Jan",
    time: "10:30 AM",
    totalFare: "1200 MUR",
    type: "Return",
  },
  {
    bookingID: "Booking ID# 41203",
    date: "Wed, 13 Jan",
    destinationAddress: "Nilkant Mandir Avenue, Vacoas-Phoenix, Mauritius",
    numberOfPersons: "1",
    pickupAddress: "Bagatelle Chanteney, Moka, Mauritius",
    requestMadeOn: "16:18:36 \nWed 13 Jan",
    time: "05:30 PM",
    totalFare: "400 MUR",
    type: "One-Way",
  }
]
```

I want to sort the data by **date and time**.

Comment: That's great. However, Stack Overflow is not a blog of what people are working on. If however, you have a question, feel free to ask it. Just make sure it is not a duplicate question.

Comment: How would "31 Dec" sort in comparison with "1 Jan". Aren't you missing a year somewhere?

Comment: Have you tryed to transform the string date into a Date class and use the attributes for comparing and creating a new array with the sort needed

Comment: @trincot I am getting data from the server which I don't have access that's why I asked

Comment: You didn't ask anything as far as I can see. You just stated that you want to sort. So let me then ask you: how will you solve the lack of a year? How will you do this when going from December to January? You already accepted an answer, but it doesn't deal with this aspect, nor could it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and parse the `date` and `time` of each element in a [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object for comparison:

```js
const arr = [
  {
    bookingID: "Booking ID# 34120",
    date: "Wed, 13 Jan",
    destinationAddress: "4, Port Louis, Maurice",
    numberOfPersons: "1",
    pickupAddress: "A 33, Goodlands, Maurice",
    requestMadeOn: "08:12:06 \nWed 13 Jan",
    time: "10:30 AM",
    totalFare: "1200 MUR",
    type: "Return",
  },
  {
    bookingID: "Booking ID# 41203",
    date: "Wed, 13 Jan",
    destinationAddress: "Nilkant Mandir Avenue, Vacoas-Phoenix, Mauritius",
    numberOfPersons: "1",
    pickupAddress: "Bagatelle Chanteney, Moka, Mauritius",
    requestMadeOn: "16:18:36 \nWed 13 Jan",
    time: "05:30 PM",
    totalFare: "400 MUR",
    type: "One-Way",
  }
];

const sorted = arr.sort(({ date: date1, time: time1 }, { date: date2, time: time2 }) =>
  new Date(`${date1} ${time1}`) - new Date(`${date2} ${time2}`)
);

console.log(sorted);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using sort you can achive this

```
var arr = [
      {
        bookingID: "Booking ID# 34120",
        date: "Mon, 14 Jan",
        destinationAddress: "4, Port Louis, Maurice",
        numberOfPersons: "1",
        pickupAddress: "A 33, Goodlands, Maurice",
        requestMadeOn: "08:12:06 \nWed 13 Jan",
        time: "10:30 AM",
        totalFare: "1200 MUR",
        type: "Return",
      },
      {
        bookingID: "Booking ID# 41203",
        date: "Wed, 13 Jan",
        destinationAddress: "Nilkant Mandir Avenue, Vacoas-Phoenix, Mauritius",
        numberOfPersons: "1",
        pickupAddress: "Bagatelle Chanteney, Moka, Mauritius",
        requestMadeOn: "16:18:36 \nWed 13 Jan",
        time: "05:30 PM",
        totalFare: "400 MUR",
        type: "One-Way",
      }
    ]
    function dateToUnix(date){
      return new Date(date).getTime() / 1000
    }
    var sorted = arr.sort(function(a, b) {
      return dateToUnix(a.date) - dateToUnix(b.date);
    });
    
    console.log(sorted)
```